# How to specify local logging when developing Flexible Environment? (Java)

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, logging

Instead of using maven goal "gcloud:run" I use "dev_appserver.py" to run my web app.

The app is an ordinary web app using Flexible Environment, Java 8, Jetty 9 in compatibility mode with Google App Engine. It uses a **appengine-web.xml** to specify a **logging.properties** file which is set to **.level=FINE**

*How do I specify logging?* Neither **java.util.Logger** or **System.out.println** seems to output anything in the console.

Comment: so maybe the logging.properties is setup to log to a file?

Comment: It was all about Jetty configuration. Just add SLF4J as dependency and it worked out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It all relies on Jetty and configuring to log. I made a solution with SLF4J. All needed is adding it as dependency.

Read more here http://aimmoth.blogspot.se/2016/06/logging-with-flexible-environment-and.html